# Using NPM and packages paths with Grunt

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I am using Grunt and it is watching files in my `src` folder. However the `baseDir` is set to src so it is serving files from that point, however it can't see back to the `node_modules` folder.

How can I set grunt to serve from the correct folder but load the necessary packages that I need to load from the node_modules folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you mean is that you're using grunt to start a local web server? If so, then there isn't a good answer for you as a web server will only have access to files in its base directory. That said, if you need to access a file in `node_modules/` from a web request you could add a [`copy` task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to move those files into a subdirectory within your `baseDir`.

Here's an example of using jQuery via node_modules - in your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
copy: {
  vendorJS: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/',
      src: ['jquery.js'],
      dest: 'src/vendor/'
    }]
  }
}
```

Then you would need to change how you pull in that file in the browser to match the `src/vendor/` directory.